# ¿Cómo preparar un Crystal Reports para una firma electrónica?

Tags: seguridad, crystal-reports, firma-digital

¿Se puede preparar un *Report* construido en *Crystal Report* para que después se pueda firmar electrónicamente? En *PDF* añades un campo de firmas en el documento, pero, ¿Se puede en Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 2):

Al parecer `Crystal Report` no tiene funcionalidad para hacer eso, pero puedes utilizar un `SDK` de terceros después de crear el archivo lo modificas y le añades la firma.

[Liga en inglés al respecto](https://archive.sap.com/discussions/thread/1877766)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que responde el experto es:

> `Crystal Report` no tiene una función automática para hacer esto, así
>   que tienes que hacerlo fuera del diseñador.
>
> Si tienes un programador disponible podría escribir una `app` sencilla
>   para correr el reporte, exportarlo y aplicar el cambio fuera de
>   `Crystal Report`.
>
> etc...

Podrías utilizar `itexsharp` después de generar el `pdf` y añadir la firma.

Comment: ya me lo temía... Muchas gracias. Investigaré la app que me pones